# while trying to use recyclerview, I can't get content in object in view holder

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I'm trying to use recyclerview and I'm trying to design 'setText' method in viewholder use number in item parameter.

The problem is that when I put "item.getNumber()" in setText method app doesn't work. I don't know why when I put just string in method have no problem and put "item.getNumber()" have problem without error message.

adapter:

```java
public class adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter.ViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<data> items=new ArrayList<data>();

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View itemView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemlayout, parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    } 

    public void additem(data item){
        items.add(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        data item=items.get(position);
        holder.setText(item);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        EditText editText;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            editText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        }

        public void setText(data item) {
            textView.setText(item.getNumber());
            editText.setHint(item.getSentences());
        }
    }
}
```

mainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static int num = 6;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        adapter adapter1 = new adapter();
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            adapter1.additem(new data("sentences", i + 1));
        }
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter1);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }
}
```

data.java:

```
public class data {
    String sentences = null;
    int number;

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public data(String sentences, int number) {
        this.sentences = sentences;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getSentences() {
        return sentences;
    }

    public void setSentences(String sentences) {
        this.sentences = sentences;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `getNumber()` method returns `int`:

> ```
> public int getNumber() {
>     return number;
> }
> ```

There are two different versions of `TextView.setText()`, one that accepts a `String` and one that accepts an `int`. The version that accepts an `int` is expecting a string resource id (like `R.string.foo`), and it can't tell that you're just trying to display a number.

Change your `setText()` call so that it looks like this instead:

```
    textView.setText("" + item.getNumber());
```

By using `"" + item.getNumber()`, you'll make sure that you're calling the version of `setText()` that accepts a `String`, and that will mean that you get to display the number you're expecting.